# Create a class for database connection in qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

HI I am a beginner in Gui development using qt.
I have a project where I have to use a mysql database. I want to know how to create a class for my connection to the database and for the query so It will be easy for me to call this class in the different windows and execute sql queries

Comment: Yeah I followed that with that:

Comment: Yeah I followed that with that:
  QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
  db.setHostName("localhost");
  db.setDatabaseName("calendar");
  db.setUserName("root");
  db.setPassword("");
  if(!db.open())
  {
     qDebug()<<("Failed to open the database");
     return false;
  }
  else
  {

      qDebug()<<("Connected");
      return true; 
I have different windows where I need to perform some queries. How can I do that

Comment: As in answer, QSqlQuery is for that purpose ..., create queries, execute them, read data, write it to controls

Comment: The connection is made in the main.cpp but how can I execute queries if I am in dialog form?

Answer (score 0):

Qt has drivers for it ... http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html, for connection you don't have create class. You should use classes for that purpose. Example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-connecting.html shows how to connect. Qt has many examples and decent documentation. To start read about classes

- QSqlQuery
- QSqlDatabase

Answer (score 0):

I can give you my source code of my class for connecting to my database. I saved my specific database data in a txt file, so if i install it on another computer I can just make the txt file fit.
Here the header:

```cpp
#ifndef DATENBANK_H
#define DATENBANK_H
#include <QtSql>
#include <QDebug>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class Datenbank
{
public:
    QSqlDatabase db;
    bool connData();
    void discData();
    Datenbank();
};

#endif // DATENBANK_H
```

And here the cpp file. should be exaxtly what you are looking for

```cpp
#include "datenbank.h"



Datenbank::Datenbank()
{


}

bool Datenbank::connData()
{
    //txt file um Datenbankdaten auszulesen
   fstream data;
   string Databasename,Hostname,Username,Password,Driver,Crapreader;

    //txt oeffnen
    data.open("Datenbank.txt",ios::in);

    if (!data.is_open())
    {
        qDebug()<<("Failed to open 'Datenbank.txt'");
    }
    //get data from text file, crapreader gets stuff which is irrelevant
    data>>Crapreader>>Driver;
    data>>Crapreader>>Databasename;
    data>>Crapreader>>Hostname;
    data>>Crapreader>>Username;
    data>>Crapreader>>Password;
    data.close();

    QString qDriver = QString::fromStdString(Driver);
    QString qDatabasename = QString::fromStdString(Databasename);
    QString qHostname = QString::fromStdString(Hostname);
    QString qUsername = QString::fromStdString(Username);
    QString qPassword = QString::fromStdString(Password);


    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(qDriver);
    db.setDatabaseName(qDatabasename);
    db.setHostName(qHostname);
    db.setUserName(qUsername);
    db.setPassword(qPassword);

    if(!db.open())
    {
       qDebug()<<("Failed to open Database");
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<("Connected.....");
        return true;
    }

}

void Datenbank::discData()
{
    QString connection;
    connection=db.connectionName();
    db.close();
    db=QSqlDatabase();
    db.removeDatabase(connection);
    //db.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
    qDebug()<<("Disc.....");

}
```